# Raspberry pi - HDMI to DVI converter

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I bought a raspberry canakit for some pi experimentation. I have a DELL computer screen but does not have HDMI input but as a DVI input.

My canakit comes with a default HDMI cable and im currently unable to connect it to the monitor.

Can I use HDMI to DVI converter cable to connect my pi? Just want to make sure I dont break any of my pi hardware by using this cable.

[https://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-HDMI-DVI-Adapter-Cable/dp/B014I8UU2W](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014I8UU2W)

Comment: you can use an HDMI to DVI-D converter, but you may need to change the colorspace on the monitor, HDMI is usually YUV, DVI is RGB... but most monitors let you change that, if not you can probably change it in some linux driver config..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a better fit on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/